# How to use ANTD in NEXTJS 13 with /app folder?

Tags: antd, next.js13

I can't for the life of me figure out how to use ANT Design v5 with NEXTJS 13 and the /app folder.

I saw the obvious 'use-client' option, but I'm not considering rendering all my pages using CSR.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you readed [antd docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next)? They have everything you need to know there and a whole example project on how to use it with nextjs

Answer (score 0):

Just started a project and ran with Ant Design into the same exact problem. As mentioned in Next.js documentation, you handle such cases like:

```
'use client';

import { Button } from 'antd';

export default Button;
```

for every antd component you use, I guess. In such a way, you only have to Client-side render the antd components, which is not ideal, but I can't find a more optimal solution for the time being.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#third-party-packages